# Consulta por el metodo MouseListener y MouseAdapter Java

Tags: java, java-swing

He creado un proyecto el cual contiene `jtextarea` y `jlabel`, añadiendole al `jlabe`l la opción del `transferhandler` para así poder arrastrar el label y que este se escriba en el textarea. Mi problema es que cuando arrastro este `jlabel` encima de otro en el mismo panel, el label se sobreescribe con el texto del que estoy arrastrando.

Les adjunto mi código.

Método que me permite mover el label cuando mantendo el click del mouse:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
  //creamos el método para transferir
  //datos al presionar con el ratón

  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    JComponent jc = (JComponent) e.getSource();
    TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
    System.out.println("tengo el label");
    th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
  }
};
```

Método que me permite agregar los `jlabel` al `jpanel` y les da la propiedad de `mouselistener` junto con el `transferhandler`:

```
if (RsNameKeyword2.next()) {
  mencion = RsNameKeyword2.getString(1);
  mencion = "\n" + mencion;
  etiqueta[i] = new JLabel(mencion);
  etiqueta[i].setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
  etiqueta[i].addMouseListener(ml);
  etiqueta[i].setEnabled(true);
  //etiqueta[i].setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(programa));
  JLabel labelFecha = new JLabel(fechaMencion);
  drag.setLayout(layout);
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = indice;
  c.fill = 1;
  c.gridwidth = 1;
  c.gridheight = 1;
  c.weightx = 1.0D;
  c.weighty = 1.0D;
  //etiqueta[i].setBounds(0, nuevoY, 30, 10);
  //etiqueta[i].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));
  //etiqueta[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40)); 
  //etiqueta[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
  //etiqueta[i].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
  drag.add(etiqueta[i], c);

  c.gridx = 1;
  c.gridy = indice;
  c.fill = 1;
  c.gridwidth = 1;
  c.gridheight = 1;
  c.weightx = 1.0D;
  c.weighty = 1.0D;
  //etiqueta[i].setBounds(0, nuevoY, 30, 10);
  //etiqueta[i].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));
  //etiqueta[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40)); 
  //etiqueta[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
  //etiqueta[i].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
  drag.add(labelFecha, c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Investigando por internet logré encontrar la respuesta a mi consulta por si a alguien más que vea esta pregunta le sirve.

`public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < drag.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                            if (drag.getComponent(i) instanceof JLabel) {
                                ((JLabel) drag.getComponent(i)).setTransferHandler(new 
                                TransferHandler("text"));
                            }
                        }
                        JComponent jc = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                        TransferHandler th = jc.getTransferHandler();
                        th.exportAsDrag(jc, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
                        for (int i = 0; i < drag.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                            if (drag.getComponent(i) instanceof JLabel) {
                                ((JLabel) drag.getComponent(i)).setTransferHandler(new 
                                TransferHandler(""));
                            }
                        }
                    }`

En el evento `mousePressed` que nos permite saber cuando le damos click y lo mantenemos en un componente, pregunto por los componentes dentro de mi `jpanel` "drag" contándolos y recorriendolos uno por uno. Después pregunto por el componente numero "i" ubicado en el `jpanel` y si este instancia de `jlabel`, le doy la propiedad de poder moverse y ser copiado en otro lugar.

Después hago el mismo paso, pero con la diferencia que les doy la propiedad del `transferhandler` vacía para que cuando tenga el `jlabel` apretado con el ratón no se puedan sobreescribir los demás.